# Detecting 11 adjacent digits with RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, string-parsing

How I can detect 11 adjacent (i.e. 11 digits no other characters in between) digits with RegEx?

i.e. it should match `asd 12345678901 asd 11` and `AA12345678901as`

but **NOT** `asd 123456789012 asd 11` because it has 12 adjacent digits

I tried `(^[0-9])*(\d{11})(^[0-9])*` but it matches `asd 123456789012 asd 11`

Comment: Adjacent digits? What does it mean? Successive or 09 or 90?

Comment: Just try `\d{11}` or `[0-9]{11}`.

Answer (score 4):

Try `\b\d{11}\b`, which specifies a word boundary around the 11 digits so you don't match the first 11 of a 12 length.

Comment: This would also reject `AA23412342345as`.

Comment: @RohitJain the regex is correct..op never mentioned such input

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ.. May be OP didn't notice this coming. But it clearly rejects 11 consecutive digits. Which is not what OP wnats.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: Doesn't matter. If the OP doesn't mention, we have to point it out the special case that the regex may behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with look-around:

```
(?<!\d)\d{11}(?!\d)
```

It will match a sequence of exactly 11 digits, and you can be sure that in front or behind it doesn't have any other digit (it can be any other characters, though, such as alphabet, space, etc.).

So these strings are considered to contain a match: `jhgjad12345678901`, `12345678901`, `12345678901skjdhks`, `sdfjhsdf 12345678901 sdfjgj 2342 sdkfl`, `=-=342_12345678901:}{]'`

Or another way, without look-around:

```
(?:\D|^)(\d{11})(?:\D|$)
```

The 11-digit number will be in the capturing group 1.

You can use `IsMatch` method with the above regex to check whether the string has a sequence of exactly 11 digits. You can use `Match` or `Matches` method to find one or all (respectively) the sequence in the string.

Comment: If the OP doesn't want to match against something like 11111111111asdf then he could try this alternative: (?<![^\s])\d{11}(?![^\s])

Comment: Ok, yeah, the double negation is silly and unnecessary.  I don't use look-arounds often.  Better alternative: (?<=\b)\d{11}(?=\b)

Comment: @RogerN: The double negation is necessary to make sure that a whitespace character or start/end of string is there. `\b` doesn't need to be in the look-around, but the modification will match `;12345678901;`, if your intent is to disallow things like this.

Answer (score 0):

That would be

```
[^\d]+\d{11}[^\d]+
```

1. at least one non-digit
2. exactly 11 digits
3. at least one non-digit

Comment: this will not match an 11-digit number on a line by itself

Comment: @dogbane: That requirement was not specified.

Comment: @RoyDictus for inputs where the 11 digits are at the beginning cuz `[^\d]` would never match `^`

Comment: @DJ: Again, that requirement was not specified.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Just you need to make sure that there is exactly one `non-digit` before and after your sequence. So, you need to insert a `[^\d]` without any quantifier at both ends.

You can try this regex: -

```
(?:.*?[^\d]|^)\d{11}(?:[^\d].*|$)
```

See demo: - http://www.myregextester.com/?r=14ad3bb5

The above regex matches following strings: -

```
asd 12345678901 asd 11
12341234234
af23412434353 saf  // 11 digits preceded by characters. I suppose you expect it to match.
```

and rejects this string: -

```
asd 123456789012 asd 11
```

Comment: You can't match `12345678901`.

Comment: you are making it way to complex..it would also not match if the digits occur at start

Comment: The modification doesn't make it any better.

Comment: @nhahtdh Some 1.Kill.. Edited Regex.

Comment: Now it matches "asd 123456789012 asd 11", which it shouldnt match

Comment: @nhahtdh That's 11 digits nested inside two characters at each end with no break, which is again not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @cms_mgr.. That's not specified in OP. OP wanted just 11 sequential digits, not followed or preceded by digits. And characters are not digits. So, it's valid.